# Upgrade Magento2.2.8 to 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, magento2.2.8, magento2.3.3

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'quote' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE `quote`

When we run setup upgrade after upgrade code I am getting this error what I do to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We got it! So first of all, before upgrading Magento version, you have to create table following the below query:

```
CREATE TABLE `quote_address` (
  `address_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Address Id',
  `quote_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Quote Id',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Created At',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Updated At',
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Id',
  `save_in_address_book` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Save In Address Book',
  `customer_address_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Address Id',
  `address_type` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Address Type',
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Email',
  `prefix` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Prefix',
  `firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middlename` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `suffix` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Suffix',
  `company` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Company',
  `street` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Street',
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `region` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `region_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Region Id',
  `postcode` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Postcode',
  `country_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Country Id',
  `telephone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `same_as_billing` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Same As Billing',
  `collect_shipping_rates` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Collect Shipping Rates',
  `shipping_method` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Description',
  `weight` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Weight',
  `subtotal` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Subtotal',
  `base_subtotal` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Subtotal',
  `subtotal_with_discount` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Subtotal With Discount',
  `base_subtotal_with_discount` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Subtotal With Discount',
  `tax_amount` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Tax Amount',
  `base_tax_amount` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Tax Amount',
  `shipping_amount` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Shipping Amount',
  `base_shipping_amount` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Shipping Amount',
  `shipping_tax_amount` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Tax Amount',
  `base_shipping_tax_amount` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Shipping Tax Amount',
  `discount_amount` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Discount Amount',
  `base_discount_amount` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Discount Amount',
  `grand_total` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Grand Total',
  `base_grand_total` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Grand Total',
  `customer_notes` text COMMENT 'Customer Notes',
  `applied_taxes` text COMMENT 'Applied Taxes',
  `discount_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Discount Description',
  `shipping_discount_amount` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Discount Amount',
  `base_shipping_discount_amount` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Shipping Discount Amount',
  `subtotal_incl_tax` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Subtotal Incl Tax',
  `base_subtotal_total_incl_tax` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Subtotal Total Incl Tax',
  `discount_tax_compensation_amount` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Discount Tax Compensation Amount',
  `base_discount_tax_compensation_amount` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Discount Tax Compensation Amount',
  `shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Discount Tax Compensation Amount',
  `base_shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amnt` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Shipping Discount Tax Compensation Amount',
  `shipping_incl_tax` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Shipping Incl Tax',
  `base_shipping_incl_tax` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Shipping Incl Tax',
  `vat_id` text COMMENT 'Vat Id',
  `vat_is_valid` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Vat Is Valid',
  `vat_request_id` text COMMENT 'Vat Request Id',
  `vat_request_date` text COMMENT 'Vat Request Date',
  `vat_request_success` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Vat Request Success',
  `gift_message_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Gift Message Id',
  `free_shipping` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Free Shipping',
  PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`),
  KEY `QUOTE_ADDRESS_QUOTE_ID` (`quote_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ADDRESS_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `quote` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Sales Flat Quote Address';
```

Let us know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The table is lacked in database. The solution is that you have to upgrade Magento version again but remember to reverse all steps before upgrading.

Comment: what step i revrese i upgrade on my local system then i move to stage same code i have database split